# What are the requirements to unlock the seasonal transmorg reward?

Tags: diablo-iii

In one of the [latest blogs](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/15522718/season-now-live-30-08-2014) about Patch 2.1, Blizzard said that we can unlock a seasonal transmogrification set by competing in the season.

> Seasons offer unique rewards and new challenges for players, including new Legendaries, **an exclusive Transmogrification set only available to those who compete in each Season**, and new achievements called Conquests. Progress within a given Season will also be tracked in our new Leaderboard system.

What exactly are the requirements to unlock this set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It states in the in-game help screen that if you reach level 70 with a season hero, you will gain the Transmogrification pieces. It was also stated that only a few pieces, each season, will be released.

[image: Screenshot of the Season screen]

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness btw I included the info yesterday in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/182798/15726).